# Getting Attribute value from dataValues in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
app.get("/" , async(req,res) => {
    let result1=await trial_table.findAll({attributes : ["emp_id","emp_name"],where : {emp_name:"abc"} ,raw:true})
    let result2=await trial_table.findAll({attributes : ["emp_id","emp_name"],where : {emp_id:1},raw:true})
    let result3=await trial_table.findAll({attributes : ["emp_id","emp_name"],where: {emp_id:1 , emp_name:"def"},raw:true})
    console.log(result1,result2,result3)
    console.log(typeof(result1))
    console.log(typeof(result2))    
    console.log(typeof(result3)) 
    console.log(result1.emp_name)  
    res.render("frontpage.ejs", { result1 , result2,result3})    
})
```

> console.log for "result1" is [{emp_id=1,emp_name='abc'}]

However When I do result1.emp_id its giving "undefined" as result.I need to get values of keys from result1.

Comment: what happens if you remove the attributes key/value?

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize `findAll()` function always returns an Array.
To fetch a single record use `findOne()`

```
const result = await trial_table.findOne({
   attributes: ['emp_id', 'emp_name'],
   where: { emp_name: 'abc' },
   raw: true
});
```

If option `raw:true` is passed, then you can do `result.emp_id`
otherwise, we have to use `.get()` to get the plain javascript object.

```
const trial = result?result.get({ plain:true }):null;
```